# Using custom styling for jQuery unobstrusive validation .NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a HTML markup like this:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="main-contact">
            <form id="registerForm">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FirstName, new { @placeholder="First Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @placeholder = "Last Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RepeatPassword, new { @placeholder = "Repeat Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RepeatPassword)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCountryId, Model.Countries, "-- Select a country --")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedCountryId)

                <button type="submit">Send message</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And using these libraries to activate jQuery's unobstrusive validation:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

And now I'm trying to add some style to the textboxes themselves and validation messages when the form is not valid... ?

I'd like to use the bootstrap's default way of displaying the messages and adding the red glow around the textbox itself... Or maybe if some of you guys have some custom css that wanna share here ?

How can I apply the default bootstrap styling to this now or add some custom one ?

Answer (score 0):

add Reference to below CDN's and modify your form to use bootstrap classes to change the UI look.

```
!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

something like this,

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "eg: details about the deal..." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

Here form-group, form-control classes are from [Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp)

Also you can refer to this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to see what classes you need to use for different form elements